# Is there a way to make Resharper keymaps plugin work in version 6

Tags: plugins, resharper

I like [Key promoter](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=1003) in [Intellij IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), then I find the equivalent one named [Keymaps for ReSharper](http://keymaps.forresharper.org/) in [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), but it doesn't work with Reshaper version 6. Is there a workaround or any other equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regrettably, Keymaps for Resharper is no longer being maintained and it isn't open-source, so you can't take existing code and port it to 6.1. The only alternative I can see is to write it from scratch.